# MySql trying to select Group By with calculation range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a product database, and I want to be able to select the count of products that are in each of 8 pricing discount groups.

The query result would be two columns, one with pricing discount group and one with the number of products within that group.

The pricing discount is based on this calculation:

(100-pSalesPrice/pPrice)

Which will result in an rational number between 0-100

This select statement:

```
SELECT (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) as pDisc, count(*) FROM ds_products where 1 GROUP BY (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice)
```

Results in:

```
0.000000 44
0.111114 1 
1.033332 3 
3.128208 3
3.142853 2
```

... ect for 100s of lines

What'd I'd like is the result that is grouped by only 8 ranges, like this:

```
15 12
25 84
35 72
45 11
55 102
65 36
75 12
76 3
```

Where each range would be:

```
15 = 0-15
25 = 16-25
35 = 26-35
45 = 36-45
55 = 46-55
65 = 56-65
75 = 66-75
76 = 76-100
```

Currently, my plan was to add a new field to my product database called pDiscountGroup and update this for each product... but I do not want to add more to my product database if I don't have to.

Is there a slick MySQL query that could accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case when for build the range you need

```
SELECT 
  case  when (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice)  <=  15 then 15 
        when  (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) >   15  and  (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) <= 25 
                                                  then 25 
        when  (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) >   25  and  (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) <= 35 
                                                  then 35 
                .... 
                ....
        when  (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice) >  75 then 100 
        end  as pDisc
     , count(*) 
  FROM ds_products 
  GROUP BY pDisc
```

Comment: I like the idea here, and it appears to work - however it gave me a very strange Server Error that I've never seen in phpMyAdmin before.

Comment: This is working for me, but I don't like the server error.  It is not an error that stops me from from using the query, but it does mention the error is reported to the webhost.... (Bluehost).

Comment: Worked!  the CASE ... END need to be in ()

Answer (score 0):

You could add another table e.g. `groups` with 3 columns: `priceGroup, min, max` (or similar names). In this table yo add your ranges, as defined in your problem:

```
priceGroup  min  max
15           0   15
25          16   25
35          26   35
45          36   45
55          46   55
65          56   65
75          66   75
76          76  100
```

Now you can make a join to this table with

```
SELECT g.priceGroup, count(*)
FROM ds_products p
    LEFT JOIN groups g ON
        (100-100*pSalesPrice/pPrice BETWEEN min AND max)
GROUP BY g.priceGroup
```

The benefit of this solution is, that it is possible to rearrange the groups, or even store a name of the group, ...